# Package amsmath not found

Tags: r, install.packages, amsmath

I have an issue with the package amsmath on RStudio. I would like to write in latex on a RMarkdown document but I can't knit my work because of this package. I don't know why I don't have it anymore because I used to use it.
I try to install it with `install.packages("amsmath")` and I have this in return :
`Warning in install.packages : package ‘amsmath’ is not available for this version of R`
RStudio is update, and when I search the package with `available.packages()` I don't find it.
I really need this package because I will write all my report on RMarkdown.

Thank you !

Comment: `amsmath` is a LateX package. Install it within your distribution of LateX…

Comment: If you're using `tinytex` in R, you could try installing with `tlmgr_install()`.

Comment: I don't know what I use but it's not tiny text because it didn't work